# ImageKit works fine on local but doesn't work on heroku why?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, heroku, imagekit

```
puts "Uploading image #{@game_id}"

kit = IMGKit.new(@game_url, quality: 50)
image_data = kit.to_png

obj = S3.object(File.join(@bucket_path, "#{@game_id}.png"))
obj.put(body: image_data, acl: 'public-read', content_type: 'image/png')

puts " ------------- image uploaded successfully -------------- "
```

This code works fine on local. When I check image it shows the correct image but when I check this by uploading on heroku it gives 0 bytes image.

Can anyone help me why this showing this type of behaviour?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your [server-side logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs)?

Comment: `wkhtmltoimage` is not available by default on `Heroku` - did you install it? See https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit#heroku

Answer (score -1):

Are you using any Cloud Storage?
If not, then configure it in your project, because Heroku can access cloud storage file only, local files on your machine is not accessible by Heroku.

Comment: Doesn't it look like they're already doing that? From the code: `obj = S3.object(File.join(@bucket_path, "#{@game_id}.png"))`, and the question is tagged with the `amazon-s3` tag.